# Best javascript regex for an address number

Tags: javascript, regex, street-address

I have a collection of all uppercase address names and numbers and I want to extract just the first encountered address number for each address. The following examples show what I would like to extract from each:

- 80 ROSE COTTAGE -> 80
- 80A ROSE COTTAGE -> 80A
- 80 A ROSE COTTAGE -> 80 A
- 80ROSE COTTAGE -> 80 (accidental no-space)
- [ANY OTHER TEXT] 80 ROSE COTTAGE -> 80

I have found some similar questions answered here and elsewhere on the internet, but they always deal with an address as a whole as opposed to specifically just address name and number:

[Match each address from the address number to the 'street type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542419/match-each-address-from-the-address-number-to-the-street-type)

[regex street address match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397485/regex-street-address-match)

[Regular Expression: Any character that is NOT a letter or number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991901/regular-expression-any-character-that-is-not-a-letter-or-number)

[javascript regular expressions address number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201427/javascript-regular-expressions-address-number)

[JavaScript regex to validate an address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153338/javascript-regex-to-validate-an-address)

The last one makes reference to a lookahead, which lead me to construct a negative look ahead for any alphanumeric characters following a potential single text character(eg. 80 A) in my JavaScript regex. However without adding the alternative "digits only found" group (\d+) my fourth example above does not return just the number.

```
(?:\d+\s*[A-Z]?(?![A-Z0-9]))|(?:\d+))
```

Is there a way to combine these two groups into a single regex expression? Or is this not possible in JavaScript's regex implementation?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciared.

Comment: Does it really have to be that complicated? An address usually has only one number which must be the number you are looking for. If it is followed by a character directly like in `80A` or if it is followed by a character encased in spaces like in `80 A ` then that is what you are looking for.

Comment: /hi thanks for your reply. The dataset is not perfect and as with my last two examples sometimes the number is not at the start, or a word following the number without a seperating space. Without using the look ahead, i found that 80ROSECOTTAGE would result in 80R when it should just be 80. Thus I have currently added the digit only alternative group. This works, but I am wondering if there is a way to combine without having the groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(\d+\s*(?:[A-Z](?![A-Z]))?)
```

You can try this.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kM7rT8/13

Comment: Hi, I am attempting to apply your suggestion to the first group in my regular expression (so that I can drop the second). The best I seem to do is: \d+\s*[A-Z]?(?![A-Z]{2,}) This works fine apart from it seems to drop the zero from 80 when the example text is '80ROSE COTTAGE'. Did you mean to apply this somehow else? What I require is: [At least one digit(s)] followed by [Any or no whitespace] followed by [Any one 'A to Z' that is not followed by another 'A to Z'] (or failing the last part, just the original digit(s)). I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @Derek you have to use .replace function.And replace with ``.and just use the regex given and nothing else.

Comment: Hi sorry I didnt realise that was the case. Am I right in thinking that carrying out a replace using this on 'A 80 A' would return 'A 80 A' as opposed to '80 A'?

Comment: @Derek it would return `A 80 A`

Comment: @Derek http://regex101.com/r/kM7rT8/12

Comment: Thanks for that, but I don't need a regular expression to replace all multiple 'A to Z' occurances with "", because as is the case with 'A 80 A' or '80 A N  A D D R E S S  W I T H  T O O  M A N Y  S P A C E S', this would return false positives. I am trying to specifically pattern match: [At least one digit(s)] followed by [Any or no whitespace] followed by [Any one 'A to Z' that is not followed by another 'A to Z'] (or failing the last part, just the original digit(s)). I have managed to do this with the two groups, but I am wondering if it can be made into a single expression with no groups.

Comment: @Derek try now the new regex

Comment: vks thank you very much, that is exactly what I was after... I hadn't considered grouping the character after digits check together as you have done in that last epxression. That is very helpful, and very much appreciated :-)

Comment: @Derek glad we could do it finally. :)